# error installing packages in linux mint

Tags: linux-mint, apt, package-management, python, dpkg

any time i try to install a package, it writes the following:

```
E: /var/cache/apt/archives/mintupdate_5.1.0.4_all.deb: subprocess new  pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
 E: /var/cache/apt/archives/python-samba_2%3a4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.3_amd64.deb: subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
```

help pls!

Answer (score 0):

Run `dpkg` with the `--force-overwrite` option:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/mintupdate_5.1.0.4_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/python-samba_2%3a4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.3_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```